# Browsing static file directory tree in Node.js/express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a public/ directory that I have set up as containing static files in express:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

It has an images directory in it

```
/public/images
```

And that has a deep subtree of various images. If I put in the full path to the image, it loads with no problem.

```
http://mysite.com/images/tiles/grass.png
```

When I just go to a url such as

```
http://mysite.com/images/tiles/
```

It just gives me the error that it gives when it tries to find a non-static path, but the path doesn't exist.

How can I make it so all directories in my static path show something similar to the way Apache shows the navigable directory structure?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Because what you're requesting when putting

```
http://mysite.com/images/tiles/
```

is a directory listing request, and it seems that **static** middleware just serves files not directories. You have to use

```
app.use(express.directory(your_path));
app.use(express.static(your_path));
```

This will let you request the URIs you're talking about.

Comment: Worked great, thanks! This isn't in the current express guide. Also required update from 2.4.4 to 2.4.7 (for anyone else who has this problem)

Comment: If you want it to use index.html files when given a path, put express.static before express.directory. Static will load the index file so directory browsing won't happen when the file is there.

Answer (score 13):

For Express 4 this looks a little different:

```
var directory = require('serve-index');
app.use(directory(your_path));
```

Check here for details:

https://github.com/expressjs/serve-index

Comment: Does it serve subdirectories too?

Comment: can i view file also?